# Google Cloud SQL JDBC Socket Facrory UnknownHostException: google

Tags: java, spring, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-sql

I want to connect to Google Cloud SQL database using JDBC Socket Factory from a Spring 4 Maven application running in Kubernetes container.

The pom.xml has:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
    <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
    <version>8.4-702.jdbc4</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.cloud.sql</groupId>
    <artifactId>postgres-socket-factory</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.14</version>
</dependency>
```

In applicationContext.xml:

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">  
    <property name="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver"></property>  
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:postgresql://google/mydb?cloudSqlInstance=myinstance&amp;socketFactory=com.google.cloud.sql.postgres.SocketFactory;"></property>  
    <property name="username" value="postgres"></property>  
    <property name="password" value="passwd"></property>  
</bean>
```

I have GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS environment variable with service account details to access cloud sql.

But I'm getting following exception:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Could not open connection
        at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:131)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:125)
        at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.begin(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:160)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beginTransaction(SessionImpl.java:1395)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.TransactionImpl.begin(TransactionImpl.java:59)
        ... 100 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The connection attempt failed.
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:150)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc2Connection.java:125)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc4.Jdbc4Connection.<init>(Jdbc4Connection.java:24)
        at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:393)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnectionFromDriverManager(DriverManagerDataSource.java:154)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.obtainConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:297)
        ... 105 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: google
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:184)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538)
        at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:434)
        at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:211)
        at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.<init>(PGStream.java:62)
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:76)
```

What could be missing here?

Comment: Do you start cloud sql proxy ?

Comment: I don't want to use cloud sql proxy, instead I want to use JDBC Socket Factory

Answer (score 0):

When using Kubernetes and Google Cloud SQL you must either use a [private IP address or the Cloud SQL Proxy Docker image](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/connect-kubernetes-engine)

Comment: I want to use JDBC Socket Factory

Comment: Have you enabled the [Cloud SQL API](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/connect-external-app#java) ?

Comment: Yes, I have enabled

Comment: Have you checked the following?

Per the [docs](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-sql-jdbc-socket-factory#user-content-authentication) the s. factory uses ADC to authenticate, and if you are using a service account you may need to have an [GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS environment variable](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production) with the json that you got when created the service account

It also may worth checking the [firewall settings](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-sql-jdbc-socket-factory#user-content-firewall-configuration)  for port 3307